# Interpolation of 3D grid data

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, labwindows

I have six point in 3D plot. For example:

```
x = [2, 28 , 44, 33, 10, 19]
y = [23, 49, 8, 42, 32, 19]
z = [23.5955, 23.7141, 23.7410, 23.5603, 23.7948, 23.6131]
```

In matlab I can use griddata function and the result:

3D Plot results:
[image]

Now I need do the same interpolation in C in LabWIndows.
I search internet and I don't find source code or example 
in C how to do linear interpolation in 3D grid plot.
Someone can help in the topic? In LabWindows I can use 
OpenGL also.

Comment: Is it just linear interpolation? If not, which type of interpolation you need?

Comment: At the start linear. Then maybe cubic etc.

Comment: Perhaps you can find good C samples in John Burkardt's code library: https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/c_src.html (e.g. the code of BLEND)

Comment: I don't understand your graph. 6 points in 3D define a 1D curve. I don't see how you can interpolate a 2D plot. Is it a minimal surface ?